# Umbraco / Sagepay : 500 / 5006 : Unable to redirect to Vendors web site. The Vendor failed to provide a RedirectionURL

Tags: umbraco, payment-gateway, umbraco7, opayo

I've integrated sagepay to an umbraco base website(V 7.4.2 MVC)

Getting code reference code from : https://github.com/JeremySkinner/SagePayMvc

request to sagepay and everything seems to work fine, but after redirecting user to sage pay web site. and entering card detail's , and conformation page

Getting following error

[image]

Notification URL looks something like: http://siteName:9003/PaymentResponse/Notify

So kindly guide me on the same , do I need to take any special care from umbraco part or so. (As I do not found any reference / sample code / blog on integrating sage pay with core umbraco ).

Thanks

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory, are you passing a redirection URL?

Comment: Yes, as shown I am passing all most the same URL(Notification URL) and have also  tried  with ApiController. kindly suggest if I am missing any thing.

Comment: Well you haven't shown any code so it's unknown what you are passing, that's why I asked! But the error clearly states you are not passing it, and the associated [SagePay help page](http://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/error-codes/5006-unable-redirect-vendors-web-site-vendor-failed-provide-redirectionurl) seems to say the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sagepay does not like URLs that contain the port (eg :9030), neither can you redirect to localhost, if this is what you tried. Unfortunately, the only way to test this is to deploy your solution and run it on a web server. If you search enough on the web, you can find some solutions involving a proxy which you could consider.

Comment: Yes, Right I have gone for sub domain , and it start working, Thanks

Comment: But now I am redirected to Blank page after collecting payment detail any Idea why it is so.  ?,Thanks

Comment: Well, it probably has to do either with an incorrect redirection URL or you fail to respond back to Sagepay. Try to put some logging on the controller/handler that is hit on the redirection URL, to see if it actually hit. If it is hit, then you probably do something wrong on your response. Otherwise, it's your redirection URL.